# Create a select all checkbox using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a select all checkbox, and I want to be able to select all other checkboxes.
In my code, if I select the select all check box, all other checkboxes are checked, but I can not solve all checkboxes later. Select all checkbox is unchecked and the other checkboxes are checked again. What is wrong with my code?

jsp

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()">ALL CHECK

<div class="floatitem" ng-repeat="assign in assignModel">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="assign.assignYn" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" ng-checked="selectedAll">{{assign.roomNum}}
```

controller

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
     if ($scope.selectedAll) {
         $scope.selectedAll = "Y";
     } else {
         $scope.selectedAll = "N";
     }
     angular.forEach($scope.assignModel, function (assign) {
         console.log(assign.assignYn)
         assign.assignYn = $scope.selectedAll;
     });

 };
```

By default, the value of assignYn is set to N. When it is checked, it must be converted to "Y", and if you select the ALL checkbox, it must also be converted to assignYn "Y"

Answer (score 0):

You are checking selectedAll to be true/false, you should check it to be Y/N instead

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
     if ($scope.selectedAll==="N") {
         $scope.selectedAll = "Y";
     } else {
         $scope.selectedAll = "N";
     }
     angular.forEach($scope.assignModel, function (assign) {
         console.log(assign.assignYn)
         assign.assignYn = $scope.selectedAll;
     });

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the true value and false value to be Y/N on the SelectedAll checkbox as well, like you have for the checkboxes in the ng-repeat.

Also, you can't use the ng-checked attribute with the ng-model attribute on the selectedAll checkbox. By setting the ng-model attribute, you are already mapping the checked attribute to the selectedAll variable. See the doco here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

HTML with true value and false value set on the selectedAll checkbox and the ng-checked attribute removed.

```
<div ng-controller="checkAllCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng false-value="'N'" ng-click="checkAll()">ALL CHECK

<div class="floatitem" ng-repeat="assign in assignModel">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="assign.assignYn" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'">{{assign.roomNum}}

</div>
```

Javascript. Notice how I've removed the assignment to $scope.selectedAll in the checkAll function. ng-model takes care of that for us.

```
angular.module('checkAllApp', []).controller('checkAllCtrl', ['$scope', 
function ($scope) {
    $scope.assignModel = [
    { assignYn: 'N', roomNum: 1 },
    { assignYn: 'N', roomNum: 2 },
    { assignYn: 'N', roomNum: 3 },
    { assignYn: 'N', roomNum: 4 },
    { assignYn: 'N', roomNum: 5 },
  ];

  $scope.selectedAll = 'N';

  $scope.checkAll = function () {
      angular.forEach($scope.assignModel, function (assign) {
          console.log(assign.assignYn)
          assign.assignYn = $scope.selectedAll;
      });
   }
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['checkAllApp']);
```

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjzxejyd/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it works...

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial','ngRoute','ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $scope.selected = [1];
  $scope.toggle = function (item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
      list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
      list.push(item);
    }
  };

  $scope.exists = function (item, list) {
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
  };

  $scope.isIndeterminate = function() {
    return ($scope.selected.length !== 0 &&
        $scope.selected.length !== $scope.items.length);
  };

  $scope.isChecked = function() {
    return $scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length;
  };

  $scope.toggleAll = function() {
    if ($scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length) {
      $scope.selected = [];
    } else if ($scope.selected.length === 0 || $scope.selected.length > 0) {
      $scope.selected = $scope.items.slice(0);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="md-padding demo checkboxdemoSelectAll">
  <div layout="row" layout-wrap="">
    <div flex="100" layout="column">
      <div>
          <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" flex="">
          <div flex-xs="" flex="50">
            <md-checkbox aria-label="Select All" ng-checked="isChecked()" md-indeterminate="isIndeterminate()" ng-click="toggleAll()">
              <span ng-if="isChecked()">Un-</span>Select All
            </md-checkbox>
          </div>
            <div class="demo-select-all-checkboxes" flex="100" ng-repeat="item in items">
              <md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">
               {{ item }}
              </md-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```